# how to make welcome dialog box appearing once with html/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have my html page have a welcome dialog box coming out when I first enter into the page. I don't want the dialog box to appear each time I load the page.  I only know html, css and javascript. is it possible to stop this dialog box appearing each time?

```
 <body  onload="welcome()"> 
    <h1>Hello World</h1>    
    <script>
            function welcome(){
    alert(" Welcome to Music.com");
        }
    </script>
    </body>
```

each time I reload the page  the welcome box appears again. How do I stop it?

Comment: Read about cookies

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: can you help me with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/JYsdN/1/

Edit: added comments

JS:

```
    //Gets the cookie with given c_name taken from w3school
function getCookie(c_name) {
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    }
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_value = null;
    } else {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
        var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1) {
            c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end));
    }
    return c_value;
}

//Sets the cookie with given c_name to given value for exdays taken from w3school
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

//Function for GUID creation
function s4() {
  return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
             .toString(16)
             .substring(1);
};

//Function for GUID creation
function guid() {
  return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
         s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}

//Checks if the user has the cookie
function checkCookie() {
    //attempts to get the cookie
    var user = getCookie("user");
    //If the user doesn't have a cookie
    if (user == null || user == "") {
        //Welcome them
        alert("Welcome!!!");
        //Create a GUID
        user = guid();
        //Set the user's cookie to their GUID expiring in 365 days
        if (user != null && user != "") {
            setCookie("user", user, 365);
        }
    }
}

//on document.ready call checkCookie
checkCookie();
```

Answer (score 3):

Well this seems to be a problem because JS can only store Data in Sessions/Cookies that won't last forever but - there is one way i can think of (except Cookies).

You can use the [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) to save that the user has already seen the Dialog.

OR you can start learning [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) - its Javascript but for server-side programming.

Answer (score 2):

In the past, I've used the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). Below is an example as to how the code would look:

```
//check for cookie - https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
if ($.cookie('FirstTime') !== 'close') {

    //show promo pop-up

    $('.promoCloseButton').click(function() {

      //hide promo

      //set cookie on close
      $.cookie('FirstTime', 'close', {
        path : '/',
        expires : 120
      });

    });

  }
```

Comment: this question isn't marked with a jQuery tag, please refrain from using a framework that the user isn't requesting.

Comment: I haven't learn jQuery yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a cookie that would last until the users session on your page ended. That way, if they refreshed the page, their session wouldn't have ended and the box wouldn't show up.  Here's a link to a simple cookies tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Please don't refer to w3schools ([w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/)) there are better sources on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Just using html and javascript you'll need to use cookies.

Set a cookie and show the div if not already been to the site.  else do nothing.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qm58q/

```
var cookie = "myCookies";
    if(!getCookie(cookie)){
        document.getElementById('welcome').className = "show";
        setCookie(cookie,"true",1)
    }


showWelcome();
```